# Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm building a `Cocoa Touch Framework`. I started using the Xcode template and then I developed all the logic. I know that the framework must be universal to run on both simulator and device, so I used the lipo command to create it (I have a run script phase). Now, the problem is that we cannot ship an app to the App Store that has a framework with slices of simulator inside itself, so we have to use the device only version. How can I automate this process? Other libraries distribute to people the `.framework` file that works everywhere. How can we reach the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use script from Realm team
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/scripts/strip-frameworks.sh

> If using Realm in an iOS, tvOS or watchOS project, create a new “Run
>   Script Phase” in your app’s target’s “Build Phases” and paste the
>   following snippet in the script text field:
>
> bash
>   "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
>   This step is required to work around an App Store submission bug when
>   archiving universal binaries.